# Microsoft sync framework increase the database size while provisioning

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I Have 2 servers in Different Location Primary and Secondary. i want to Sync Data between it. I was using Microsoft Sync Framework to do this activity. i have Successfully done sync but my database Size increased from 6 GB to 30 GB (Round about 5 times from actual). I am searching for solution about this. but i not Found.

Can any body help to control the database Size.

Comment: Is it the database that has grown, or the log file?

Comment: Yes, Both Database and Log file are grown.